# Recognizing Street curbs

Tags: google-maps, gps, mapping, gis

I'm not a coder but I have hired a coder who has told me there is not a way to do the following. I want to use any mapping platform (that will do this if it is at all possible) that recognizes street curbs. So for example if I take a picture of a parking sign the geo location of the picture will automatically snap to the curb rather than just rely on GPS location which has a 19 foot error margin. Again just a layman looking for a solution to a problem and would love your feedback!!

Thank you,

David

Comment: Your programmer is correct - this is a fantastically difficult problem - impossible to implement reliably with current "off the shelf" technology.  Maybe in the future when robot vision is way more advanced than it is now - but if you had a system that did it you could probably publish it as a PhD thesis.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to get a camera that works with a laser range finder.  Target the range-finder on the parking sign and the camera can calculate how far you are from the sign and in which direction (provided that you have calibrated the compass).   Keep in mind that you're still going to get, at best, about a 13-foot margin around that sign with most cameras.  The only way to get closer than that is to use a sub-meter GPS receiver separately.  I don't know of any cameras with that precision.